# If $A\subseteq B$, $B-A$ is infinite, $A$ is countable, then $B-A\sim B$

Tags: set-theory

> If $A\subseteq B$, $B-A$ is infinite, $A$ is countable, then $B-A\sim B$.

Here $\sim$ means "as numerous as", which is a stronger condition compare to the just being "coutable/uncountable", i.e. different uncountable set may not be equally numerous, e.g. real number and power set of real number. I am trying to use Schröder–Bernstein theorem (this should be easier than constructing a bijection between two sets) here by showing $B-A\preceq B$ and $B\preceq B-A$.

$B-A\preceq B$ is trivial. However, how would I approach the other direction?

Some background: $X\preceq Y$ means there exist an injective map from $X$ to $Y$.

Edit (cr. to Anne Bauval): infinite set $X$ is defined as set that satiesfies $\mathbb{N}\preceq X$.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you hoping for? An *eplicit* construction of an injection $B\to B\setminus A$ most probably needs a well-order of $B$. But then you are close to cardinal arithmetic which directly implies your claim since $|B|=|A\cup (B\setminus A)|=\max\{|A|,|B\setminus A|\}=|B\setminus A|$ because countability of $A$ implies $|A|\le |C|$ for every infinite set $C$.

Comment: You should make explicit in your post your [definition for 'infinite set'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933535/what-is-the-definition-for-an-infinite-set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a countably infinite subset, $X$, of $B-A$. We inject $B$ into $B-A$ as follows:

Inject $X\cup A$ into $X$ (using odds and evens) and map the rest of $B$ to itself.

Answer (score 4):

$B-A$ has a countably infinite subset $A'$, so write $B = (B-(A \cup A')) \cup A \cup A'$ and $B-A = (B-(A \cup A')) \cup A'$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $C=B-A$ and it is an infinite set.

First of all it's obvious than $C$ is at least countable. So there is an injection
$$f: \mathbb{N}\to C$$
So we can say that
$$C = f(\mathbb N) \cup (C-f(\mathbb N))$$
You need to prove
$$f(\mathbb N)\cup (C - f(\mathbb N)) \cup A \sim f(\mathbb N)\cup (C - f(\mathbb N))$$
Also it is obvious that $f(\mathbb N)\cup A\sim \mathbb N$, so here is a bijection
$$g : \mathbb N \to f(\mathbb N)\cup A$$
We then need to prove
$$g(\mathbb N)\cup (C - f(\mathbb N)) \sim f(\mathbb N)\cup (C - f(\mathbb N))$$

The latter is also obvious if we note that all the cups above are exclusive.